Number of discrete Lipschitz functions with given Lipschitz constant
Fix $T, K, N \in \mathbb Z_+$. How many distinct Lipschitz functions $f: \{0, \dots, T\} \to \mathbb Z$ are there with Lipschitz constant $K$, and supremum norm at most $N$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$?
In probabilistic language, this question asks for the probability that the discrete uniform random walk with allowed steps $\{0, \pm 1, \dots, \pm K\}$ remains within the interval $[-N, N]$ for a time $T$.

In more usual terminology, the question asks what is the probability that the discrete random walk starting at 0 with allowed steps ${0,\pm1, \ldots, \pm K}$ does not leave the interval $[-N, N]$ for time $T$.

Yes, that is how the problem arose for me… @FedorPetrov

Maybe I should’ve just given the probability formulation, ha.

When $K\ge N$, we can view this as counting the number of strings of length $T$ over a $(2N+1)$-symbol alphabet with adjacent symbols differing by at most $K$. See for example https://oeis.org/A126473 when $K=3$ and $N=2$.

Just a comment: if you're happy with estimates of the growth rate, it should be possible to get this by a suitable rescaling from the probability that a standard Brownian motion stays in an interval $[-\alpha,\alpha]$ up to $T$.

Yep, that should allow to obtain good estimates @AnthonyQuas. However, and I am not sure if I am being too ambitious, but I think this can actually be directly counted…
